# How to swap two fields of a struct

Tags: struct, reference, rust, swap

I've started studying Rust and I'm trying to implement a simple 1D cellular automata. I want to represent the automata state (`Board`) as struct holding the size and two different vectors (of same size). I tried:

```
struct Board {
    n: usize,
    cur:  Vec<u32>,
    next: Vec<u32>,
}

impl Board {
    fn new(size: usize) -> Board {
        Board {
            n: size,
            cur: vec![0;size],
            next: vec![0;size],
        }
    }
}
```

So far so good. I'm also able of mutating both vectors. But then I want to be able to swap both vectors (or rather their references), such as:

```
fn swap(&mut self) -> &Board {
    let tmp = self.cur;
    self.cur = self.next;
    self.next = tmp;
    self
}
```

It fails, with an `cannot move out of borrowed content [E0507]` which I think I can understand. I also tried `mem::swap` which I found in a similarly title question without success.

How can I make this example work ? (Since I'm a total beginner with Rust, don't hesitate to suggest a different data representation).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you noticed, `mem::swap` is the way to go:

```
fn swap(&mut self) -> &Board {
    std::mem::swap(&mut self.cur, &mut self.next);
    self
}
```

This works. Note that when using `.` you are dereferencing `self`. So while `self` has the type `&mut Board`, `self.cur` has the type `Vec<u32>`. Therefore the compiler complained about "move out of borrowed content" and we need the additional `&mut`s.

Answer (score 6):

> What's the problem?

You are **punching holes** in your data:

```
fn swap(&mut self) -> &Board {
    let tmp = self.cur;         // 1
    self.cur = self.next;       // 2
    self.next = tmp;            // 3
    self
}
```

If we analyze line by line:

1. `self.cur` is now uninitialized
2. `self.next` is now uninitialized
3. everything is kosher again

If for some reason computation is interrupted before line (3) has a change to tighten up the situation, `self` is now poisoned and may cause all kinds of nasty things to happen. Notably, its destructor could attempt to free memory twice for example.

In theory, you could have the compiler check for temporary holes and prove, without doubt, that:

- no function accesses `self` while a hole is punched
- by the end of the scope, whether it is reached normally or by unwinding, the holes are filled up again

and indeed at some point it was considered... but the truth is that it's complicated and there are readily available work-arounds.

> So?

The answer lies in `std::mem` which exposes functions to perform such low-level operations in a safe manner. While the functions themselves are implemented using `unsafe` under the hood, they lean on their understanding of the language and runtime to expose safe interfaces.

The two particular functions that will interest you are:

- `replace`: replaces the content of `dest: &mut T` by `src: T` and returns the what was previously contained behind `dest`
- `swap`: exchanges the content of its arguments

With those two simple and safe primitives, you can avoid punching holes in your data.